# Cannot find Remote.SSH: Remote Server Listen On Socket in my local VS Code User settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where is the Remote.SSH: Remote Server Listen On Socket setting in VS Code? I cannot find it following the instructions in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_improving-security-on-multi-user-servers.

Visual Studio Code Remote Development Extension Pack v0.20.0

VS Code:

Version: 1.47.2 (user setup)

Commit: 17299e413d5590b14ab0340ea477cdd86ff13daf

Date: 2020-07-15T18:22:06.216Z

Electron: 7.3.2

Chrome: 78.0.3904.130

Node.js: 12.8.1

V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [as the option says](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_ssh-host-setup), it's only valid for Linux and macOS remotes.

Answer (score -1):

Goto File >> Preferences >> Settings Or press 'Ctrl + ,', you will getting settings page opened.

Under left side menu, select 'Extensions'.

You will find 'Remote - SSH' listed. Click on that item.

All the settings available for 'Remote - SSH' will be shown on the right side.

Comment: There is no Remote-SSH options in this path.